# Java property map printing issue

Tags: java, loops, printing, properties

I want to create an app that takes in properties using e.g `-dMyProps=123` (not parameters (args)). I understand the properties is then in a map. so i would get it using.

```
public void getProperties() {

map myMap = System.getProperties();    
myMap.get();
...
```

If there are multiple properties how do I read them all and print them all?

`System.out.println(whatever needs to printed here);`

If someone can assist me, I think it must be done in a for loop or enhanced for loop, but I'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `map myMap = System.getProperties();` , `map` is `java.util.Map` which is actually incorrect.
`System.getProperties();` will return you a `Properties` class object;which can be itreated according to your requirement.As for eg:

`Properties prop = System.getProperties();`

`Set<Object> set= prop.keySet();` `//Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map.`